# React is not getting images from local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, express

[image: Code Example]

Hey guys I have an node express server running on port 5490 and with postman or navigate through links from moz I have the jpeg file display in screen as response, but in react I can't even loaded, anyone knows what is happening? image 1 is react component not displaying the image, and second image is expressstatic files...

[image: express example]

Comment: Try specifying the protocol, eg. `http://`, in the source url.

Comment: Hi gitialn4gual and welcome to SO. Please create codeblocks in which you show your code as text instead of images.

Comment: if you are using relative path for images in your react components, did you check whether the base href (the context for the relative paths) of your html page is set properly? A quick way to check this is to use your browser debugger, look for the image src either in the html or css depending on how you load the image and check the url by opening it in another tab.

Comment: thanks all, is the first one. "http://" sorry for the trouble, and the next post I will give text examples to show my code. you're great!